# Count the occurrence of value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have an array as below:

```
values = [["Cat", true], ["Dog", false], ["Cow", false], ["Owl", true]]
```

Now I want a code in `ReactJS` to check how many `true` are there and how many `false`.

Someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) & [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

```js
let values = [
  ["Cat", true],
  ["Dog", false],
  ["Cow", 1],
  ["Owl", 0],
  ["donkey", 0]
]
let truthy = 0;
let nonTruthy = 0;
let trueCount = 0;
let falseCount = 0;

values.forEach(ele => {
  if (ele[1] === true) trueCount++;
  if (ele[1] === false) falseCount++;
})

values.forEach(ele => {
  ele[1] ? truthy++ : nonTruthy++
})

console.log(trueCount, falseCount) // 1 1 
console.log(truthy, nonTruthy) // 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question about react, but about javascript.

One way to go about that is to write a method that counts all occurences.

```
values.filter(item => item[1] === true).length
```

This will filter out only items that are TRUE and return the length of this array.
Same can be done for filtering false values, or you can subtract true values from the length of the array if you're sure you only have true and false values throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
 const values = [["Cat", true], ["Dog", false], ["Cow", false], ["Owl", true]];
  let counter = 0;
  values.map((item) => {
    if (item[1]) {
      counter++;
    }
  });
  console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achive it is to use filter

```
const values = [["Cat", true], ["Dog", false], ["Cow", false], ["Owl", true]];

const trueVals = values.filter(item => item[1]).length;
const falseVals = values - trueVals;
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with the values array, but if it keeps its formation you can use this:

```
let filteredArray = values.filter((val) => val[1] === true).length;
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of `flat()` then filtering it out:

```js
var values = [["Cat", true], ["Dog", false], ["Cow", false], ["Owl", true]]
var result = values.flat().filter(k=>k==true).length;
console.log(result);
```